# Full-wave rectifier problem

Tags: rectifier

I am studying full-wave rectifier now.

[image]

here is the circuit that I made and then I connected oscilloscope between K and L.

As I've learned from the classroom, this circuit has to make full-rectified signal

However, when I measured the voltage between point K and L, I got this result.

[image]

I've tried to think what is the problem here, but I can't figure it out.
Is it kind of related to floating ground?

I really don't know what's the problem here.

Can you help me please?

thanks ahead.
and sorry if I sound like rude...I am studying English as well...

Comment: If you measure between K and L, you will only get one trace. Did you by any chance measure K to ground and with the second channel L to ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you surmised you can't easily look at the signals on a scope if the AC source is referenced to ground.

You need to get a floating AC source, for example a secondary on a transformer.  The your scope ground can connect to point C or D and measure the voltage at the other points such as G and H.

Comment: thank you guys for the reply. I will try both methods you mentioned: changing probes and measuring voltages in different points. thanks again. have a nice day or night